# Macbook pro won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro

My 2008 macbook pro won't turn on.

I replaced the battery less than six months ago, but it seems that it died again.

The charger is connected and it shows a green light, but the battery's lights don't turn on. When the battery button is pressed, only the first light blinks.

I tried resetting the SMC multiple times, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you're using an 85W Apple MagSafe adapter, the 60W will **not** provide enough power to turn the MacBook Pro on.  Try with a known-good 85W MagSafe adapter, if that doesn't work, you'll need to take it into an Apple Authorised Service Provider (AASP) or the Genius Bar.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the Battery and then turning the Mac on?

If the Mac starts you can then insert the Battery and it should recharge.

If the MacBook does not start (without the Battery inserted) then your Problem is more likely a faulty AC-Poweradapter.

Comment: just tried it. I tried with 2 different power adapters and nothing...

Comment: Just to be clear: you removed the Battery and tried to start the Macbook, using two different Power Adapters, but you couldn't start your MacBook with any of them?